# get response from expo sqlite query

Tags: expo

According to Expo documentation with SQLite I would make a query like so:

```
tx.executeSql(sqlStatement, arguments, success, error)
```

I execute it like this:

```
db.transaction(tx => {
  tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM dr_report_properties WHERE orderId = (?)', [this.state.orderId]);
},
  error => {
    alert(error);
  },
  (tx, results) => {
    console.log(results);
  }
);
```

My question is how do I get the response?  The above returns as undefined. 
I then try (not expecting it to work but just for kicks)

```
console.log(tx);
```

This does give a console.log

```
(tx, results) => {
        console.log('I got data');
      }
    )
```

According to the documentation:

```
ResultSet objects are returned through second parameter of the success callback for the tx.executeSql() method on a Transaction (see above). They have the following form:
{
  insertId,
  rowsAffected,
  rows: {
    length,
    item(),
    _array,
  },
}
```

I would expect result would be this object.  Any ideas at what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

The problem with the above was that I placed the call AFTER the execution it's actually in the same method as that.

The result should have gone in the callback like so:

```
db.transaction(
      tx => {
        tx.executeSql('select * from my_table', [], (trans, result) => {
          console.log(trans, result)
        });
      }
    );
```

Thanks to @charliecruzan from expo team!